# Share ViewModel across Fragments with Dagger Scopes in Single Activity App

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger, android-viewmodel

The [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#create_a_new_layout_to_host_the_ui) recommends a Single Activity Architecture, and the page on [Dagger](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#dagger-subcomponents) recommends sharing common ViewModels across Fragments using Dagger scopes.

But this requires having a parent Activity from which the Fragments get the Dagger component, as shown in this line from the docs: `(activity as LoginActivity).loginComponent.inject(this)`

This is kind of pointless when you only have a single Activity across your app as that's basically the same as using the `@Singleton` scope for the lifetime of your whole app. It also prevents you from using [FragmentScenario](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing#create) for testing your Fragments as they are now tied to your specific Activity.

What's the best way to share a single ViewModel through Dagger, across Fragments, without giving it a `@Singleton` scope or tying it to an Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're talking about `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel` which manages its own lifecycle and **should not** have **any scope** to allow for it to do just that. If you add your own scopes on top it'll just end up with broken and/or confusing behavior.

As such you shouldn't inject those ViewModels directly either but use the ViewModel factories and lookup methods, or—again—you'd end up with broken and/or confusing behavior since the ViewModel would behave differently to what all of its official documentation states. (You may write a bunch of boilerplate to move this process into modules, but ultimately you'd still need to let androidx manage the lifecycle)

If you don't want to use `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel` but want to get the same/similar behavior then you'd have to create your own scope in-between components. That scope should live *shorter* than the application, but *longer* than any single Activity instance to allow for those objects to be reused after configuration changes and so on.